# Android Camera Api v2 issue

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have 2 Android PDA 401 (android 6.0). The one has a camera 5MP and the other one have a camera 8MP.
My application use Camera API v2 to take picture. So I'm facing an issue that Camera Preview of 5MP phone is
brighter than the 8MP phone. I expected that 8MP one is brighter than 5MP one. I have 2 questions:
1/ is Camera Api v2 incompatible with camera 8MP module? Quality of camera 8MP is bad
2/ if root cause is that Camera Api v2 is incompatible, so is there any workaround? 
any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

```html
<p>photo from Camera 5MP</p>
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/uC8Ql9j" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/uC8Ql9j"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```html
<p>photo from camera 8MP</p>
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/d3JERUv"><a href="//imgur.com/a/d3JERUv">PDA 401 with Camera 8MP</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi device according to the pixel of the camera to make a distinction and if you do operations according to him I think the problem will be solved. The following codes contain information about how many pixels the camera has. Good coding to you

```
        Camera camera=Camera.open(0);    // For Back Camera
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size  result = null;

    ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForWidth = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayListForHeight = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
        result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
        arrayListForWidth.add(result.width);
        arrayListForHeight.add(result.height);
        Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
        System.out.println("BACK PictureSize Supported Size: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);  
    } 
    if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
        System.out.println("Back max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));              // Gives Maximum Width
        System.out.println("Back max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));                 // Gives Maximum Height
                    System.out.println("Back Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
    }
    camera.release();

    arrayListForWidth.clear();
    arrayListForHeight.clear();

    camera=Camera.open(1);        //  For Front Camera
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params1 = camera.getParameters();
    List sizes1 = params1.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size  result1 = null;
    for (int i=0;i<sizes1.size();i++){
        result1 = (Size) sizes1.get(i);
        arrayListForWidth.add(result1.width);
        arrayListForHeight.add(result1.height);
        Log.debug("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
        System.out.println("FRONT PictureSize Supported Size: " + result1.width + "height : " + result1.height);  
    } 
    if(arrayListForWidth.size() != 0 && arrayListForHeight.size() != 0){
        System.out.println("FRONT max W :"+Collections.max(arrayListForWidth));
        System.out.println("FRONT max H :"+Collections.max(arrayListForHeight));
                    System.out.println("FRONT Megapixel :"+( ((Collections.max(arrayListForWidth)) * (Collections.max(arrayListForHeight))) / 1024000 ) );
    }

    camera.release();
```